# How to check for blank values in Pandas dataframe converted dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, csv

My dataframe is as follows:

```
   Pet Number OnlinePolicyNumber Policy Number Title   Client DOB  Claim Amt Paid Excess 
       74      BW1209-186145    BW00000743   MRS               NaN           0.00      0
      226      BW1209-186297    BW00002260    MS        2019-07-10        3325.56    100
```

I want to fill the NaN values conditionally. I'm doing it as follows:

```
        df_records = df.to_dict('records')

        for column in df_records:
            rec = {}
            if column['Client DOB']:
                column['Client DOB']=parser.parse(column['Client DOB'])
                rec['ClientDOB']=tz.localize(column['Client DOB'])
            else:
                rec['ClientDOB']="1900-04-07 06:02:27.748631+00"
```

But I'm running into the following error:

> TypeError: Parser must be a string or character stream, not float

I have tried type,instance methods to check the datatype and then pass the blank values in the else statement but running into the same error again.
I'm unable to understand how I should bypass the condition.
Any help with this will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no column `Client DOB` in your example data.

Comment: @mcskinner There is a column Client DOB. This is just a part of the dataframe that I shared. There are over 40 columns in my df. I'll edit my question accordingly toavoid confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though the value for `Client DOB` is missing and marked as `NaN`, it still evaluates to `True` as part of an `if` condition.

The quick fix is to use `pd.isnull` for your check.

```py
for column in df.to_dict('records'):
    rec = {}
    if not pd.isnull(column['Client DOB']):
        column['Client DOB'] = parser.parse(column['Client DOB'])
        rec['ClientDOB'] = tz.localize(column['Client DOB'])
    else:
        rec['ClientDOB'] = '1900-04-07 06:02:27.748631+00'
```

If possible, it would be faster to use `fillna` and other vectorized methods to do everything.

```py
df['ClientDOB'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Client DOB'].fillna('1900-04-07 06:02:27.748631'))
```

Comment: yes. I solved my issue using fillna. It worked for me. Thank you.